# Side of a regular n-gon given the distances to $ 3 $ vertices of an interior point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We consider a point $ P $ inside a regular n-gon, the distances $ a, b, c $ from the point $ P $ to $ 3 $ consecutive vertices are given and we want to find the side $ s $ of the n-gon.

If $ n = 3 $ we can calculate $ s $ as the solution of $ 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + s^4) = (a^2+ b^2 + c^2 + s^2)^2 $.

If $ n ≥ 4 $ I found a formula by  H . Eves ("Solution to problem 187", $ College Math. J. $, **13** (1982) , 278 – 282), but when I try to use it for simple cases it's not working, so I guess there is some sort of error. Do you know the correct formula?

[image]

Comment: In the formula you found, it seems like $a,b,c$ cannot alternate, so perhaps there is some additional constraint ($a\geq b\geq c$ for example)?

Comment: @yanruijie $a$ and $c$ can be swapped, so I reckon $b$ must be the distance to the middle vertex.

Comment: Try the following formula: $$s^2=\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2+2 b^2 \cos \phi +c^2\pm\frac{1+\cos\phi}{\sin \phi} \sqrt{\left(2 b^2 (1-  \cos \phi)-(a-c)^2\right) \left(2 b^2 (1-  \cos \phi)-(a+c)^2\right)}\right)$$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I tried with your formula, using $ a= 5; b = 7; c = 9 $, but isn't working, because the output is not $ \sqrt{129} $

Comment: Can you explain the test case you are using? What is the value of $n$, and why do you expect the output to be $\sqrt{129}$?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sorry you are right! $ n = 3 $ so the case is just a point inside an equilateral triangle, and it's easy to find with the other formula I posted, valid for this specific case, that $ s = \sqrt{129} $. Please note that I typed a wrong value for $ c $, $ c = 8$

Comment: There is minus lost under root. Try $$s^2=\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2+2 b^2 \cos \phi +c^2\pm\frac{1+\cos\phi}{\sin \phi} \sqrt{-\left(2 b^2 (1-  \cos \phi)-(a-c)^2\right) \left(2 b^2 (1-  \cos \phi)-(a+c)^2\right)}\right)$$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you!

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I tried with the equilateral triangle and $ a = 3; b=4; c= 5 $ but the output is wrong, it should be $ \sqrt{25 +12 \sqrt{3}} $

Comment: Formula gives $s^2=\frac12 (50\pm 24\sqrt{3})=25\pm 12\sqrt{3}$. One of these is $s=\sqrt{25+12\sqrt{3}}$.